# How to load a phtml file only for homepage? (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, phtml, home, conditional-loading

I am trying to load a phtml file like this:

**File** */app/design/frontend/name/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml*

```
    <referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="startphoto" template="html/startphotos.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="section" xsi:type="string">homepage</argument>
                <argument name="position" xsi:type="number">0</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

I want to load it only on homepage, but it is still loading on every page. The arguments seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As per as, Magento2, `default.xml` is call at every page.If you add this code at `default.xml` then it ***would be automatically call every pages of your current theme.***

If you know  about ***Magento 1.x handler concept*** then you can understand  that `default` is a handle  **which is called at every pages**.In *Magento 2.X*,e**very handler is individual  layout  files.**

So if want to add **a phtml file only at home page** then you need to add that code at `cms_index_index.xml` (`/app/design/frontend/name/themename/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml`) layout file because of `cms_index_index` is handler which **call only called at home**

Comment: If I need to call my customise module in product page using only module XML file, how to do it ? Like add download linked in before add to cart button without change on catalog_product_view.xml file.

Comment: If you created a custom module then create  `catalog_product_view.xml` at  your  `app\code\[vendorname]\[ModuleName]view\frontend\layout`* write at here

Answer (score 10):

You can use xml to do this task

Inside `cms_index_index.xml` put xml like this

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <container name="block.container" htmlTag="div" htmlId="slider.container" htmlClass="block-home-container" before="">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="block.banner" as="block.custom.cms" template="Magento_Theme::block.phtml" after="-" />
        </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 5):

Create xml file name with `/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <referenceContainer name="page.top">
     <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="startphoto" template="Magento_Theme::html/startphotos.phtml">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="section" xsi:type="string">homepage</argument>
            <argument name="position" xsi:type="number">0</argument>
        </arguments>
     </block>
  </referenceContainer>         
</page>
```

Comment: better include the path for the xml file,it will improve the answer more.Thanks

Comment: If you use this XML file like this, where would the `html/startphotos.phtml ` be, relative to the xml file? I can't figure it out.

Comment: updated answer check it