# load a phtml for homepage (include phtml, theme path)

Tags: magento2

i just installed magento 2.1 on localhost, in \app\design\frontend there is only a Magento folder. The logo is using luma.

i've read this post 
[How to load a phtml file only for homepage? (Magento 2)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108296/how-to-load-a-phtml-file-only-for-homepage-magento-2)

But my problems is if i create this

```
/app/design/frontend/name/themename/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml
```

**What is the name and themename (exact path) should be**, anyone know? And if i use this code in above xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <referenceContainer name="page.top">
     <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="startphoto" template="Magento_Theme::html/startphotos.phtml">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="section" xsi:type="string">homepage</argument>
            <argument name="position" xsi:type="number">0</argument>
        </arguments>
     </block>
  </referenceContainer>         
</page>
```

What is the **exact path of startphotos.phtml** should be?

"UPDATE 1"

i have placed the cms_index_index.xml at

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\m2\app\design\frontend\randomname\theme-frontend-luma\Magento_Theme\layout
```

and startphotos.phtml at

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\m2\app\design\frontend\randomname\theme-frontend-luma\Magento_Theme\template\html
```

But nothing appear in homepage, any ideas? Should i need to use any command make it appear?

"UPDATE 2"

i have created a theme copy from `vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma` to `C:\xampp\htdocs\m2\app\design\frontend\randomname\luma_clone`

layout location: `app\design\frontend\randomname\luma_clone\Magento_Theme\layout`

phtml location: `app\design\frontend\randomname\luma_clone\Magento_Theme\template\html`

nothing appear.

"UPDATE 3"
The problem was solved because of template**(s)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you have given looks for the template in

```
/app/design/frontend/name/themename/Magento_Theme/template/html/startphotos.phtml
```

edit: Oh, I see it is a multi-part question.

The name and themename should be your company and you childthemes name. Please see the official documentation on how to create a theme:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

To create a child-theme, please see this:
[How to create a Child Theme in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108684/how-to-create-a-child-theme-in-magento-2)

Comment: what is the default theme/theme name of fresh installation? Does it include in fresh install?

Comment: i found the theme is using vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma which parent theme is blank, so who to load a phtml under this theme?

Comment: Using vendor means you have installed magento2 using composer. You should not edit anything in the vendor folder. Create a luma childtheme in app/design and only place those files in there you wish to override. See the link in my answer. Please mark the answer if it helped you.