# default.xml is loading in all pages of magento2

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to display some static content in home page using **default.xml**.

But that content is loading in all pages of magento2.

I want the static content on home page only.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue using **default.xml**?

Comment: use cms_index_index.xml for only home page

Comment: Refer this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108296/how-to-load-a-phtml-file-only-for-homepage-magento-2

Comment: Share your code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On same location create `cms_index_index.xml` and add your code init.

for example :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="yourBLockClass" name="YourBLockName" template="YourPhtmlPath.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: i created that file cms_index_index.xml in that location but it is not taking.  Whether I need to configure that cms_index_index.xml file some where else ????

Comment: @BhaskarCPothineni  no , it will call automatically

Comment: First we need to delete the  default.xml, and create cms_index_index.xml  in the same folder  . is it correct ??

Comment: @BhaskarCPothineni no , both files were called at a same time

Comment: Okay Bro ,   I will  try that and inform to you. jst give me 10 min..

Comment: @BhaskarCPothineni If my answer solves your question then you can hit that `✓` button next to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Add your phtml file in `cms_index_index.xml(/app/design/frontend/{theme vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml)` layout file because cms_index_index is handler which calls only called at home.

If you don't have `Magento_Cms` folder under your theme you need to create that with `Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml` with below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
         {{Your XML code will here}}
    <body/>
</page>
```

Comment: The Theme Which i was created, that e doesn,t have the Magento_cms folder.

Comment: You need to create that as `Magento_Cms/layout` and then create with xml with `cms_index_index.xml`

Comment: @BhaskarCPothineni, I have updated answer.